# apache fop: Show placeholder when transparent image can't be displayed in pdf/a

Tags: java, pdf, apache-fop

Transparent images are not allowed in pdf/a standard. Therefore apache fop transformation will fail with an exception, when a xml with an embedded transparent image is transformed to a pdf/a.

Is it possible to display an error image placeholder when fop fails to embed an image into pdf/a?
I thought about calling some java code to check if the image is transparent before rendering the image into the pdf? Is that possible?

Best

Comment: Transparent images are certainly "allowed in the PDF/A standard". It just depends which part of the PDF/A standard you're talking about. While PDF/A-1 doesn't support transparency, PDF/A-2 and PDF/A-3 do support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the PDF part to PDF/A3 and everything is working. Thanks.